# Scala best practices: simple Option[] usage

Tags: scala, null

As a Java-to-Scala switcher, I routinely find myself rewriting null handling stuff like

```
val itemOpt: Option[Item] = items.get(coords) // "items" is something like a Map
if (itemOpt.isDefined) {
  val item = itemOpt.get
  // do something with item, querying item fields a lot of times, for example
  if (item.qty > 10) {
    storeInVault(item.name, item.qty, coords)
  } else {
    storeInRoom(item)
  }
}
```

I guess it looks ugly and it *really* looks like a piece of code rewritten from Java's:

```
Item item = items.get(coords);
if (item != null) {
  // do something with item, querying item fields a lot of times, for example
}
```

It also looks ugly in Java, but at least it's one line less. What is the best practice to handle such simple cases in Scala? I already know of `flatMap` and `flatten` to handle collections of `Option[Stuff]`, and I know of `getOrElse` to handle default values. I dream of something like:

```
items.get(coords).doIfDefined(item =>
  // do stuff with item
)
```

but I don't see anything like that in `Option` API.

Comment: This might help: http://dibblego.wordpress.com/2008/01/16/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very popular usage pattern:

```
val item: Option[Int] = None
val result = item map (_ + 1) getOrElse 0
```

so you just use `map` in order to transform value if it's defined.

If you just want to use value, that is stored within an `Option`, then just use `foreach`:

```
item foreach { it =>
    println(it)
}
```

As you can see, `Option` also supports many collection methods, so you actually don't need to learn new API. You can just treat it as a collection with either 1 or 0 elements.

Answer (score 7):

This should accomplish what you are looking to do:

```
items.get(coords).foreach{ item => 
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, just use for comprehensions `for(item <- maybeItem) {...}` where `maybeItem` is your option.

Comment: To be even more frugal, note:
`items.get(coords) map { item => //...`

Answer (score 5):

Check this Tony Morris [post](http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/). It helped me very much when I tried to understand Option. Your code may be rewritten in such way:

```
for (item <- items.get(coords)) { // "items" is something like a Map
  // do something with item, querying item fields a lot of times, for example
  if (item.qty > 10) {
    storeInVault(item.name, item.qty, coords)
  } else {
    storeInRoom(item)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, Option could be used in Pattern Matching with `if` guard. personally I like use it in this scenario, and think it is easier to read.

Because `map` on a Option will only has effect when you Option is not `None`, so you could do it first, and then using Pattern Matching to inspect to see if your itemOpt is a `Some` or `None`.

```
def shouldInVault(item: Item) = item.qty > 10

val itemOpt: Option[Item] = items.get(coords).map(...)

itemOpt match {
    case Some(item) if shouldInVault(item) => storeInVault(item.name, item.qty, coords)
    case Some(item) => storeInRoom(item)
    case None =>
}
```